# Uploading 360 degree videos via Youtube Api

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, 360-degrees

I use the Youtube v3 Api(PHP and C#) for uploading videos. Also I need to upload 360 degree video now. But i did not see any answer at Developer Docs or Google. I couldn't be sure about that 360 degree video uploading is supporting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube provides the Google APIs Client Library for Python that uploads a YouTube video using the YouTube Data API. Client libraries for other popular programming languages are also available. The sample script does not do error handling.

Requirements:

Install the Google APIs Client Library for Python (google-api-python-client)

Register your application with Google so that it can use the OAuth 2.0 protocol to authorize access to user data.

To use OAuth 2.0 steps with the script, you'll need to create a client_secrets.json file that contains information from the Developers Console. The file should be in the same directory as the script.

Full details, sample requests and sample code here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i have no any issue about the normal video uploading. My question is about the 360-degree videos are supporting by yotube api? How can i upload them?